# Globally remove the ? button from windows titles in qt applications

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am writing a c++ application on windows using qt and qt always places this "?" Button in the window title. Currently i am removing it in the constructor of each class which is very annoying.
Is there a way to globally remove the button from the whole application in a single place?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Never seen that.

Comment: @Mat: He speaks about that: this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way but if you need it for all dialogs/windows you may create base class and unset this flag in its constructor:

```
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
```

Then use this base dialog in all your dialogs instead QDialog.

Answer (score 1):

I have a custom `QDialog` where all further dialogs are derived from which does (mostly) nothing except that.

```
class dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        dialog(QWidget* = 0, Qt::WindowFlags = 0);
};
```

---

```
dialog::dialog(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) : QDialog(parent, f)
{
    setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
}
```